# How to import a CSV file to R with the right column types

Tags: r, csv, import

My `test.csv` file is:

```
a;b;c
x;;
y;1.2;3
z;2.4;5
```

I tried to import this file to dataframe `test` using this script:

```
library(readr)
test <- read_delim("data/test.csv", 
                        ";", escape_double = FALSE,
                        na = c("empty",""),
                        col_types = cols(.default = col_character()),
                        trim_ws = TRUE)
```

But variables `b` and `c` should be `numeric` but are `character`. I tried to change `col_types` but without result. 
Edit: This a more realistic sample:

```
Country/Territory;WBCode;Estimate;StdErr
Aruba;ABW;;
Andorra;ADO;1,32;0,48
Afghanistan;AFG;-1,29;0,34
```

Comment: Based on this simple example, `readr::read_delim("test.csv", ";")` seems to work OK. Is your actual file more complicated than the example?

Comment: Yes it is. I think this sample is better: ```Country/Territory;WBCode;Estimate;StdErr
Aruba;ABW;;
Andorra;ADO;1,32;0,48
Afghanistan;AFG;-1,29;0,34```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated example, it looks like what's causing the issues is the CSV uses `,` as the decimal marker. You can read it in with:

```
readr::read_delim("test.csv", ";", 
                  locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))
```

This produces:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  `Country/Territory` WBCode Estimate StdErr
  <chr>               <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Aruba               ABW       NA     NA   
2 Andorra             ADO        1.32   0.48
3 Afghanistan         AFG       -1.29   0.34
```

Comment: Yes you're right. I just also discovered this issue.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `read.csv` or `read.table` instead

```
text <- "a;b;c
         x;;
         y;1.2;3
         z;2.4;5"

df <- read.csv(text = text, sep =";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: chr  "x" "y" "z"
# $ b: num  NA 1.2 2.4
# $ c: int  NA 3 5
```

---

Based on the updated example, you can specify the decimal mark with `dec` in `read.csv`

```
text = "Country/Territory;WBCode;Estimate;StdErr
        Aruba;ABW;;
        Andorra;ADO;1,32;0,48
        Afghanistan;AFG;-1,29;0,34" 

read.csv(text = text, sep = ";", dec = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#  Country.Territory WBCode Estimate StdErr
#1             Aruba    ABW       NA     NA
#2           Andorra    ADO     1.32   0.48
#3       Afghanistan    AFG    -1.29   0.34
```

Comment: Your solution works with my first example but not with a more realistic sample. Please see my new edit.

Comment: @sbac Updated the answer based on that.